# How to auto Tune for live view in Nikon D780

Tags: nikon, autofocus

I found my lens and camera weren't give to me good results and I resolved to tune it.

I was able to tune for **Finder** but not for **Live view**.

I didn't find any information on how to auto-tune or tune for live view. The way I found using Af-Mode button + record button for a few seconds results in a setting for Finder and not live view.

Does anyone know how to do it?
I'm not really a fan to take pictures in Live View but I would like to have this correct in my gear.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setup menu to access the options instead.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is how to auto setup for the viewfinder and not auto setup for live view. Should I use the same values?

Comment: IDK, none of my Nikons have had separate fine tuning for live-view...